# PDF reading with iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf

I would like to know if there is a method to load pdf in a different way of using WebView. What I'm trying to do is a "book reader" where I can use the fancy "flipping page".

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I hate page flipping, it smacks of nostalgia.  what's up with scrolling?  @IssamTP but if that's what you want, do it.

Comment: Just a bit of fancy for the app: I guess that most people would prefer the flip page that's why I'd implement it. If it's too much work: actually my app does the job  greatly :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always make your own parser and renderer, but it seems way too much work. Perhaps you can attach a custom animation of a UIWebView, but I'm not sure how you'd paginate etc.

```
//Your best bet is to subclass PDFView to make your custom reader, in my opinion.
```

Edit: PDFView isn't available yet. But check out the sample code: QuartzDemo. It uses transformations on a PDF that you perhaps could modify to do what you want.

Comment: Seems that it's not available for iOS... :(

Comment: Hm. You're right, Apple haven't made a framework to support it on iPhone yet! Edited my answer.